# Angular - easiest way add event all "p","span","h1" elements

Tags: html, angular, events

I am trying to add a "double click" event to all text html element (p, span, h1, h2 ...) from all pages to open a popup. 
I think that should be a better way than add to every element (dblclick)="funtion()".
I tried modify the component "p" but doesn't work...

Anyone have idea how can I do it?

I'm working in the solution like these on the AppComponent constuctor, but... I don't like it

```
router.events
  .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
  .subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {

    $("p").dblclick(function() {
      alert("Handler for .dblclick() called.");
    });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your elements in a div which handles the event.

```
<div (dblclick)=function()>
...elements..
</div>
```

Comment: What if they are in different areas? The event needs to go to that particular element and not the whole parent.

Comment: I need for every p in all pages

Comment: @Raugaral you might want to create a universal selector using jQuery on the app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<body (dblclick)="myFunction($event)">
......your code.....
</body>
```